# How to get json value of input form in codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I have a `json` variable and I want to post it as a `json` format.

```
$json_value = json_encode($my_array);
...
echo '<input name="myvalue" type="hidden" value="'.$json_value.'"  />';
...
```

in my function :

```
    $posts = $this->input->post();
    echo $posts['myvalue'];
```

but it is empty .

my `form` works correctly as I can fetch other values of inputs .

Comment: can you show your `$json_value` content?

Comment: you can use `base64_encode()` instead of `json_encode()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change Your input to use single quotes inside

```
echo "<input name='myvalue' type='hidden' value='$json_value'  />";
```

since you are using double quotes inside and  `$json_value` also has double quotes so there is a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

`json_encode` encoded values have quotes. So your hidden element value will break when first quote appears. There are some other methods to send php array using forms. I am adding one method here.

```
//On html side
foreach($my_array as $value) {
    echo '<input name="myvalue[]" type="hidden" value="'.$value.'"  />';
}

//On posted server side
$posts = $this->input->post();
$my_array = $posts['myvalue']; //<-- you can get your array here
```